# Who is the subject in the following sentence?

Tags: translation

I am a translator from Japanese into Italian and I have translated a long text, it is the scrap of novel and not from the beginning, so it has been very difficult for me to understand. The following are the sentences which I am not sure to have properly translated. Could you help me?

> ポンポンと軽く**お手玉してみて**も、爪は消える気配を見せない
>   "Even if they try to escape easily one after the other, the claws show no sign of disappearing"

Is the action of お手玉してみて performed by the nails? (爪)

Comment: a) In the future, please make sure that you are logged in when editing your own posts; b) Editing a closed post is discouraged and you should have made a new post instead. Any potential answer will be delayed because the post is closed (but is currently pending for votes to reopen).

Comment: @oals >"Editing a closed post is discouraged and you should have made a new post instead." Is that right? I was under the impression one *should* edit on-hold questions to make them acceptable if possible.

Comment: Editing a closed post is encouraged *if* the purpose is to help the question get reopened.

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/okqN_vbNC7M) is お手玉, and the subject of the first clause is the speaker (or the hero) of that story.

Answer (score 2):

お手玉 are small, traditionally handmade beanbags which are utilized as toys by juggling them. So making the word into a verb, お手玉する, makes it in reference to the concept of juggling.

> ポンポンと軽くお手玉してみても、爪は消える気配を見せない。
>
> Even having tried lightly juggling (something), the nails show no sign
>   of disappearing.

Although that sentence seems very strange out of context, I hope it makes sense to you? It seems as though there is someone with retractable claws that believes through the distraction of juggling their claws might retract... but they don't?

The claws are not what is performing the action in the first clause though, if that helps you.